# Habilitar (configurar) Ctrl + Click nas funcões no VSCode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Existe como configurar ou habilitar a opção semelhante a IDEs como phpstorm onde se utiliza o atalho Ctrl + Click nas funções do código e o editor VSCode faz o hyperlink da mesma?

Att.